# Why can not I use the word attribute a table with the column name as Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, attributes

I simply `rails g scaffold test name:string attribute:string value:string` used the command.

But when I save fill out the form, I get the error with the active recorder attribute column.

According to my research gem 'safe_attributes' gemfile, it solves this problem. I did the installation.

This time in NoMethodError in Tests#new

`private method 'attribute'` called for error.

Extected source (around line # 20):

`<% = f.text_field :attribute %>`

How can I solve the problem? Can you help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I using a reserved word in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553048/am-i-using-a-reserved-word-in-rails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is already defined private method `attribute`
And since we access model fields via `method_missing` when you try to call `Test#attribute` you get private method

The `attribute` method definition is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb#L82

To avoid this problem don't use model attributes that have the same names as already defined methods.

Comment: I added a link to the method definition. So you can't use it as attribute name.

Comment: @EmrahYıldırım Every language and framework has keywords you cannot use. You can pursue something else than programming or get over it, that's the way it is.